# Data stored in json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have my data stored in a JSON string like these...

```
a:1:{s:15:"s2member_level1";s:1:"1";}
```

How can i read this values in mysql?

I need to know if the value "s2member_level1" is 1.

Thanks!!!

Comment: That's a bad table design. You shouldn't store serialized data in your database. Re-design your table to satisfy the least 3NF, but 5NF would be nice.

Comment: is usermeta wordpress table, can't change it.
the plugin store the data in this way.

Answer (score 5):

That's not JSON but a string resulted from calling [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) in PHP. You cannot parse it easily in MySQL. If you can use PHP, use the [`unserialize`](http://php.net/unserialize) function:

```
$obj = unserialize($data_from_mysql);
if ($obj['s2member_level1'] == 1) {
    // more code here
}
```

You can convert data to JSON in PHP using the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) function. In a similar way, you construct an object from a JSON string using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode).

Answer (score 1):

@Lekensteyn is correct, but you could do a `like` statement, although its performance would most likely be very poor. My true answer is to change how you store this information to take advantages of best performing queries.

```
select * from table
where column like '%s:15:"s2member_level1";s:1:"1";%';
```

Comment: thanks but is usermeta wordpress table, can't change it. the plugin that i am using stored data inthis way.

Answer (score 0):

@Lekensteyn is right about the type of this particular String, but for others, PHP has [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which you can use to convert a JSON object to a PHP object.  It would be considerably more difficult to read such an object using MySQL only.

Answer (score 0):

This is no json, but serialized data. It was probably serialized with the 'serialize' function of PHP. Try:

```
print_r(unserialize('a:1:{s:15:"s2member_level1";s:1:"1";}'));
```

... to unserialize it.